# Typescript: Infer string literal values as a type from function argument or generic type passed in a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, inferred-type

I'm trying to build a typescript library for learning purpose, For a better developer experience I want typescript to infer the string literal type from one of the argument passed in function which is an array of objects.

For example:
Let say I've a fruit array object, an object that contains name property which can store a string value.

```js
const fruitArray = [
  { name: "apple" },
  { name: "orange" },
  { name: "banana" }
]
type FruitArray = typeof fruitArray
```

Now I've a function that takes this array object as first argument, and second argument that takes one of the fruit.name.

```js
function getFruitName<T extends FruitArray>(fruitArray: T, name:T[number]["name"]) { /** ... **/ }
```

When I invoke this function with required arguments it shows `typeof name` is `string` in `getFruitName` function.

```js
getFruitName(fruitArray, "apple")
```

the name argument can only be one of the values present in name property of fruit object. I want typescript to infer that string to string literal of those values,

```js
// Typescript should infer type of name like this instead of string
type name = "apple" | "orange" | "banana"
```

I can achieve this by making the `fruitArray` as const.
[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwE4FcCWMCCSkEMCecAvHANrByVwDecEuAtgKYBccARLgA5cA2T7ADRxcAc1ZwAjHAC+gilVr1mbdmDwRxQkeLYAmWfKo06jCewBGuevW1iJAZlnAAuiKhxw0GAG5gwGHwuJjgAMVQMbDxCEkDgsARECKwcAn8EFAgQGDRIOHEYcPQYADkzAB4AFTgmAA8YJggAEw8iyNT8AD4ACmRiqII2SuFlCUrSCBQGCyYkF1J2UfYXAEoTAHoAKk24ADp9uG31538CttKzXuSB-GFLawf2Ff8gA)

```js
const fruitArray = [
  { name: "apple" },
  { name: "orange" },
  { name: "banana" }
] as const;
```

I don't want to do this. The reason for this is that If I declare `as const` I lose the type for the array objects while writing and there are more properties other than name.

The developer experience I want using this function is that, user put in the first argument which contains the array of objects with name property in it, and then when they try to add second argument the only available options would be one of the values in array object name property.

I don't even know whether it is possible or not. Any suggestion is welcome.

### Update:

One of the issue that I faced using `as const` is that I don't have type safety while writing the `fruitArray`, that can be solved by using `satisfies` operator. As [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) mentioned in this [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAIJzgQxFAvFOCTAEwHsA7AGxwG8pzMBbCALigGdg4lyBzAGiiZeregkYAjCHCgBfANoBdANwAoVQGMKnKADNEKdFhz55qqBah0GzNgCJMYMJQh3Bw0QEY5-c5etMonakWHyu7iJsAEw+fhYBtlB2EpgMDG5CkVAAzLGKQuxQWuQ67JjASOy6SBCF8MhoGNhqqroI5BoVFFAiwPUoAHKBADwAKlAQAB7AEOTEdQaNxgB8ABT6DUbYbKOCNqKj8uTiUnCK8nb7dooAlFZQAPQAVE9QAHQfUC8Pcuqqvf1gENmOtFlsQIJkqloXYbuogA)

But I would prefer to handle the typing of name in string literals on library side itself, that would be perfect since it won't require user to do extra work to get the type safety in name argument.

```js
// Library Code
type Fruit = {name:string, age:number}

function getFruitName<T extends Fruit[]>(fruitArray: T, name:T[number]["name"]) { /** ... **/ }



// using library
const fruitArray:Fruit[] = [
    { name: "apple", age: 1 },
    { name: "orange", age: 2 },
    { name: "banana", age: 3 }
]

getFruitName(fruitArray, "") // should infer string literals from fruit Array
```

We can make any changes to library code itself.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the as const assertion mistake, I've edited the question, and any changes are acceptable that can solve this other than `as const` assertion.

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible.  When you write `const fruitArray:Fruit[] = ...` you've already thrown away the information you want to retrieve.  The user will *have* to do "extra work" to preserve the information.  The best you can do is make your library tell the user about this, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP1Jkw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does. For now it's impossible. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately what you are asking for is impossible.  Once you've written this code

```
const fruitArray: Fruit[] = [
    { name: "apple", age: 1 },
    { name: "orange", age: 2 },
    { name: "banana", age: 3 },
]
```

it is too late for the compiler to help you.  Since `fruitArray` is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as being of type `Fruit[]`, that's all the compiler knows about `fruitArray`.  (If `Fruit[]` were a a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then the compiler could [narrow `fruitArray` upon assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to just those union members compatible with the assigned value.  But it's not, so no such narrowing happens.)

Essentially, the type annotation *throws away* any more specific information the compiler may have had about the value you assigned to the variable. If you want to preserve such information you cannot annotate the type, and you will even want to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so that the compiler infers something more specific than `{name: string, age: number}[]`.  And if you care about making sure the value conforms to the type you wanted to annotate, then you should use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to do so.

Indeed, for some literal expression `{...}`, the assignment `const x: T = {...}` tells the compiler that you don't particularly care about that literal expression, while `const x = {...} as const satisfies T` tells the compiler that you do care.  Your library users essentially have no choice but to do the latter instead of the former.

---

The only possible suggestion I could make is for your library function to *detect* that the user has failed to declare `fruitArray` properly, by complaining unless the `name` property of its elements are [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of just `string`.  Here's one way to do that:

```
function getFruitName<T extends Fruit>(
    fruitArray: readonly T[],
    name: StringLiteral<T["name"]>
) { /** ... **/ }

type StringLiteral<T extends string> = string extends T ? Invalid<
    "Your fruit array has forgotten its names; go back and use a const assertion on it"
> : T;

interface Invalid<T> {
    __errorMessage: T;
}
```

The idea is that `StringLiteral<T["name"]>` will evaluate to `T["name"]` if and only if `T["name"]` is a string literal type (well, if it's narrower than `string`).  Otherwise it will evaluate to `Invalid<"...">`, an incompatible type containing a message the user can hopefully understand (this is a workaround for the lack of custom compiler errors in TypeScript, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689)).

So if you call it incorrectly, you get an error:

```
const badFruitArray: Fruit[] = [
    { name: "apple", age: 1 },
    { name: "orange", age: 2 },
    { name: "banana", age: 3 },
];
getFruitName(badFruitArray, "oops"); // error!
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
// 'Invalid<"Your fruit array has forgotten its names; go back and 
// use a const assertion on it">'
```

which hopefully prompts the user to go back and fix their mistake:

```
const fruitArray = [
    { name: "apple", age: 1 },
    { name: "orange", age: 2 },
    { name: "banana", age: 3 },
] as const satisfies readonly Fruit[];

getFruitName(fruitArray, "banana"); // okay
```

It's not perfect, but at least users will be alerted that something has gone wrong.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)